# How do I add a structured ODBC data source to a tabular model using the AMO tabular library

Tags: c#, ssas-tabular, analysisservices

Adding a structured ODBC data source to my model results in an error.

I want to generate a tabular model on a SQL Analysis Services server with compatibility level 1400 using the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular library using structured (ie. M / Power Query), non-legacy (ie. ProviderDataSource) data sources.
I installed the library using NuGet package Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64 (16.3.0).

Here's my data source definition.

```cs
                myDatabase.Model.DataSources.Add(new StructuredDataSource()
                {
                    Name = "ODBC",
                    Description = "An structured ODBC data source definition",
                    ConnectionDetails = new ConnectionDetails()
                    {
                        Protocol = DataSourceProtocol.Odbc
                    },
                    Credential = new Credential()
                    {
                        AuthenticationKind = AuthenticationKind.UsernamePassword,
                        EncryptConnection = false,
                        Username = "MYUSERNAME",
                        Password = "MYPASSWORD"
                    }
                }
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
COM error: Microsoft.Data.Mashup; The given data source reference is not a valid data source.
```

It doesn't give me any pointers where to look or what is wrong specifically. I suspected the definition needed a server address, but the address property of the ConnectionDetails object cannot be set according to the documentation.

```
ConnectionDetails.Address Property

Address of this connection. It can't be set, instead it should be modified directly.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reviewing my question and off course further investigating the documentation, I constructed this solution. For those who struggle with the same problem, I figured it'd be nice to post it here.

```
Credential credential = new Credential()
{
    AuthenticationKind = AuthenticationKind.UsernamePassword,
    EncryptConnection = false,
    Username = "MYUSERNAME",
    Password = "MYPASSWORD" // Please note that this won't persist.
};

ConnectionDetails connectionDetails = new ConnectionDetails("{ 'protocol': 'odbc', 'address': { 'options': { 'dsn': 'MYODBCDSN' } }, 'authentication': null, 'query': null }");

dbWithDataSource.Model.DataSources.Add(new StructuredDataSource()
{
    Name = "ODBC",
    Description = "An ODBC structured (ie. non-legacy) data source definition",
    ConnectionDetails = connectionDetails,
    Credential = credential,
    Options = new DataSourceOptions( "{ 'hierarchicalNavigation': true }" )
}
```

What I basically did, was pass in a JSON string in the ConnectionDetails constructor, setting the 'read-only' address property as well.